# PHP EXIF Process IFD TAG Remote Integer Overflow

Tags: php, apache, exif, integer-overflow

**Background:**

I have been working on an issue whereby a file upload form will only accept certain images, it is not a problem with image size(dimensions) or with size(filesize) but I think i've found it's to do with image bit depth, as the PHP script resizes the image and applies a static (semi-transparant) watermark file to the image and saves the result.

I have gone through a long process today and yesterday working with this as the error that occurs is the server stating **"Connection reset by server"** . Which I *think* I've narrowed down to the server not having enough free memory to complete the image resource manipulations.

**Issue:**

Then, after all that, this error comes up on file upload submission:

> IPS detected for "WEB PHP EXIF Process IFD TAG Remote Integer Overflow -2 (CVE-20/Buffer Over Flow"

Some googling only tells me that it's a securty vulnerabiliy for PHP < 4.2 or so, and doesn't relate to actually what's going on.

I have looked through my code and am very sure that 
My query is to try and shed some light on what this error statement means (and how I can go about correcting it)?

**Notes:**

- PHP 5.6.16
- No PHP EXIF functions run on the page.
- I can't see anywhere on the page that would cause an integer overflow (running to infinity, I guess)
- Page does use `imagecopy`, `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha` But this error notice *seems* to appear before the script runs on the uploaded file.
- This error only occurs on *some* uploaded images and not on others.
- I have found no Apache error logs relating to this
- I have no PHP errors recorded.

**Code:**

As I think the issue *may* occur somehow before the page loads I'm not sure how useful this code block will be but, take a look:

*(also please note that I am aware this page is 5 years old and isn't the smartest programming, i have fixed it up in parts but am aware it can probably be further tidied)*

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
///first set out variables.

$goodImage = 0;
$maxfilesize = (int)$_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'];
$gallery = (int)$_POST['galfolderid']
if (empty($gallery)) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $gallery . "<br/>Gallery Value has not been set.";
}
elseif (!is_numeric($gallery)) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $gallery . "<br/>Gallery Value is not a numeric value.";
}
elseif (!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/gallery/" . $gallery )) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $gallery . "<br/>Gallery Value, while being a number, is not a valid numeric value.";
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['message'])) {
    header("Location:editgallery.php?gallery=".$galleryid);
    exit;
}
for($count=0;$count<5;$count++) {
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'][$count] == 0) {
        clearstatcache();
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $imageType = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count]);
        finfo_close($finfo);
        unset($finfo);

        if (strtolower($imageType) == "image/png") {
            $imgtype  = "PNG";
            $original = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count]);
        } elseif (strtolower($imageType) == "image/jpeg" || strtolower($imageType) == "image/jpg") {
            $imgtype  = "JPG";
            $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count]);
        } else {
            //not a JPG or PNG type... set error.
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Image " . ($count+1) . " does not appear to be a valid .JPG or .PNG file. ";
            error_log($_SESSION['message']);
            header("Location:editgallery.php");
            exit;
        }
        unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count]);

        $edgePadding    = (int)$_POST['WMedge'][$count]; //integer
        $watermarkScale = $_POST['WMscale'][$count]; //float
        $h_position     = $_POST['Hpos'][$count]; //text array
        $v_position     = $_POST['Vpos'][$count]; //text array

        $Hoz = $h_position[0];
        $Vez = $v_position[0];


        if (!isset($watermarkScale) || empty($watermarkScale) || !is_numeric($watermarkScale)) {
            $watermarkScale = 1.0;
        }
        elseif($watermarkScale > 2.0) {
            $watermarkScale = 2.0;
        }
        elseif($watermarkScale < 0.5) {
            $watermarkScale = 0.5;
        }
        if ((!isset($edgePadding) || empty($edgePadding) || !is_numeric($edgePadding)) && $edgePadding !== "0") {
            $edgePadding = 5;
        }
        // be sure that the other options we need have some kind of value

        if ($_FILES['image']['size'][$count] > $maxfilesize) {
            $_SESSION['message'] .= "Image file ".($count+1)." appears to be too big. There is a limit of 2Mb on the
            size of the image you can upload. Please click 'Back' on your browser and resubmit a valid image.";
            error_log($_SESSION['message']);
            //file too big.
        }

        //target name is the number of images in the LARGE gallery,
        ///cycle through imagenames to find the first "clear" image number.
        $newimagename = 1;
        clearstatcache();
/***
NOTE: Only possible place an integer oveflow might occur I think
***/

        while (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/gallery/" . $gallery . "/S/" . $newimagename . ".jpg")) {
            $newimagename++;
        }
        ///newimagename is the new filename of the image.


        $target_name = $newimagename . ".jpg";
        $target      = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/gallery/" . $gallery . "/L/" . $target_name;
        $targetSmall    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/gallery/" . $gallery . "/S/" . $target_name;
        //targetSM is used below to make the thumbnail image. for the SMALL gallery.
        //full target directory and name.
        // file upload success
        // now file need resizing before the watermark is applied.

        // resize new dimensions (Large- 800px)
        $originalImageSize[0] = imagesx($original);
        $originalImageSize[1] = imagesy($original);

        /***
        * Resize new dimensions for small thumbnail.
        ***/
        if ($originalImageSize[0] > 133) {
            $percent = 133 / $originalImageSize[0];
        } else {
            $percent = 1;
        }

        $newThumbHeight = $originalImageSize[1] * $percent;
        $newThumbWidth  = $originalImageSize[0] * $percent;

        // Resample
        $imageThumbFinal = imagecreatetruecolor($newThumbWidth, $newThumbHeight);

        imagecopyresampled($imageThumbFinal, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newThumbWidth, $newThumbHeight, $originalImageSize[0], $originalImageSize[1]);

        // Output
        imagejpeg($imageThumbFinal, $targetSmall, 80);
        imagedestroy($imageThumbFinal);
        unset($imageThumbFinal, $percent,$newThumbWidth,$newThumbHeight);
        /***
         * End Thumbnail generation.
         */

        /***
         * Resize main sized image (max 800px wide)
         ***/
        if ($originalImageSize[0] > 800) {
            $percent = 800 / $originalImageSize[0];
        } else {
            $percent = 1;
        }

        $newPictureHeight = $originalImageSize[1] * $percent;
        $newPictureWidth  = $originalImageSize[0] * $percent;

        // Resample main image to reduce max size.
        $imageCleanFinal = imagecreatetruecolor($newPictureWidth, $newPictureHeight);

        imagecopyresampled($imageCleanFinal, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newPictureWidth, $newPictureHeight, $originalImageSize[0], $originalImageSize[1]);


        /***
         * Now resize the watermark and save onto the final image.
         ***/
        //full target directory and name.
        $watermark = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/watermark2.png";
        $wmTarget  = substr($watermark, 0, -3) . "tmp"; //image/watermark2.tmp is resized.
        $sourceWaterImage   = imagecreatefrompng($watermark);
        $waterMarkWidth  = imagesx($sourceWaterImage);
        $waterMarkHeight = imagesy($sourceWaterImage);

        $destinationHeight = $waterMarkHeight * $watermarkScale;
        $destinationWidth  = $waterMarkWidth * $watermarkScale;

        $destinationHeight  = floor($destinationHeight);
        $destinationWidth = floor($destinationWidth);
        $destinationWatermarkImage = imagecreatetruecolor($destinationWidth, $destinationHeight);
        imagealphablending($destinationWatermarkImage, FALSE);
        imagesavealpha($destinationWatermarkImage, TRUE);

        imagecopyresampled($destinationWatermarkImage, $sourceWaterImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destinationWidth,
            $destinationHeight, $waterMarkWidth, $waterMarkHeight);
        imagedestroy($sourceWaterImage);
        unset($sourceWaterImage);
        clearstatcache();

        /***
         * Set watermark location on final image.
         ***/
        $differenceX = $newPictureWidth - $destinationWidth;
        $differenceY = $newPictureHeight - $destinationHeight;

        switch ($Hoz) {
            // find the X coord for placement
            case 'left':
                $placementX = $edgePadding;
                break;
            case 'center':
                $placementX = round($differenceX / 2);
                break;
            case 'right':
                $placementX = $newPictureWidth - ($destinationWidth + $edgePadding);
                break;
            default:
                $placementX = 0;
                break;
        }
        switch ($Vez) {
            // find the Y coord for placement
            case 'top':
                $placementY = $edgePadding;
                break;
            case 'middle':
                $placementY = round($differenceY / 2);
                break;
            case 'bottom':
                $placementY = $newPictureHeight - ($destinationHeight + $edgePadding);
                break;
            default:
                $placementY = 0;
                break;
        }
        /***
         * Finish set Watermark location
         ***/
        imagecopy($imageCleanFinal,
            $destinationWatermarkImage,
            $placementX,
            $placementY,
            0,
            0,
            $destinationWidth,
            $destinationHeight);

        imagejpeg($imageCleanFinal, $target, 80);

        /***
         * Image final save
         ***/
        // Output
        imagejpeg($imageCleanFinal, $target, 80);
        imagedestroy($imageCleanFinal);
        imagedestroy($destinationWatermarkImage);
        unset($imageCleanFinal, $percent);
        unlink($wmTarget);
        $output[$goodImage]['targetName'] = $target_name;
        $output[$goodImage]['targetAddr'] = $target;
        $goodImage++;

    } elseif (!isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$count]) || ($_FILES['image']['error'][$count] != 0 && $_FILES['image']['error'][$count] != 4)) {
        //error in file upload.
        $_SESSION['message'] .= " There is a file upload error number " . $_FILES['image']['error'][$count] . ". for image ".($count+1).".
         Please try resubmitting a valid image.";
        error_log($_SESSION['message']);
    }
}
if (empty($_SESSION['message'])){
    $_SESSION['message'] = $goodImage." New Image(s) Uploaded";
}
// display resulting image for download
header("Location:editgallery.php?special=yes&gallery=".$galleryid);
exit;
```

**Server Details:**

- Apache 2.4
- WebHostManger & CPanel (combined) version 54.0.19
- PHP 5.6 using Mod suPHP 0.7.2
- 2 core 2.2GHz (so x2) intel with
- 1896Mb/2097Mb physical memory (used/available)
- +4095Mb memory Swap File. (~6010Mb total)

Comment: Sounds like you have a forward IPS that is preventing upload of images that would trip [PHP bug #60150](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60150).

Comment: @bishop thanks for the link that looks like it, definitely. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the layout / info. from the bug report details, it's closed so am I right in thinking if I download and replace the server version exif with `ext/exif/exif.c` linked from the bug fix that should sort it. Sorry probably an obvious question :-/

Comment: I don't think upgrading PHP will fix this error, for two reasons. First, this error string does not exist within the PHP exif extension source code for version 5.6, which you indicate you're using. Second, the error string contains the string "IPS", which strongly suggests to me that there is an Intrusion Protection System hardware/software component that's scanning the image EXIF *before* PHP gets it.

Comment: @bishop Thanks, I think I was being hopeful! I have had a look on WHM but see no sign of corresponding firewall program (so I guess it may be outside the scope of WHM)

Comment: Doesn't hurt to be optimistic! Please post what hosting provider and server OS you're using. That may help pin down the source.

Comment: @bishop I've added some server stats to the bottom of the question.